# My child process cannot receive the last value from parent process using Pipe

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe, fork

in my program, child process should receive some value from keyboard, and send to parent process. Parent process should calculate the sum and return to child process. My program is shown below:

> 3 4 5
>   -1 child(4753): Sending 3 to parent Parent(4751): Received 3 Parent(4751): Sending 3 back Parent(4751): Received 4 Parent(4751):
>   Sending 7 back Parent(4751): Received 5 child(4753): Received 3
>   Parent(4751): Sending 12 back Parent(4753): Received 4 Parent(4753):
>   Sending 7 back Parent(4753): Received 5 Parent(4753): Sending 12 back

From the result, the last step is  Parent send 12 back  but child cannot received 12 and show the total sum. 
Therefore, anyone has some ideas why the result is not my expected and how to modify my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code is not using the parameters to the `main()` function, so the main() signature should be: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile, it is missing the header statements for the `wait()` function.  I.E. `#include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/wait.h>`,    When compiling, always enable all the warnings, the fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `while(buf[i]!= -1)` should also be checking that the input buffer is not overrun (which would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event)  Suggest: `while( i< 1024 && buf[i]!= -1)`

Comment: inside the `while(buf[i] -1)` loop, this line: `pid = getpid();` overlays the information from the call to `fork()`, And following pass through the `while()` loop will be using incorrect information.

Comment: the posted code is closing the pipes before all the values (past the first value) have been processed.   So no communication will occur after the first data transfer via the pipes.  in the parent process, the call to `wait()` occurs after the first communication sequence, so the child will never receive any more communications.  However, the child will not exit until all the communication sequences are completed.  So everything will hang

Comment: Thanks for suggestions!!! However, do u have some ideas about how I can make the child to exit after receive all the value from parents? I try some methods, my pipe always lost  some data between child and parent. Due to there is while() loop in my code, I am confused about how to process the child and parent correctly.

Comment: the child knows when all the data from the parent is transfered because the child is using the same data array as the parent, so knows the number of entries.   Note: a pipe is just a string of bytes, so should be sending some kind of delimiter between the data items then read the pipe, byte by byte, accumulating bytes until the delimiter is encountered, then the reader of the pipe knows a complete data item is received.  An implied delimiter is (if sending binary data) when sizeof(int) bytes are received.

Comment: What happened to the code?  we cannot (reasonably) guess as to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent process just runs to an end without waiting for the child to finish. Thus the child is killed before it can actually print a result.

You need to add a `wait()` or `waitpid()` in the proper place of the parent process.

Comment: I have added   wait(NULL);  at end of parent process, after close(fd[P2_WRITE]); , but it shows the same result.  Do u have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The `wait` should actually be before the `close`s. Your child might receive a SIGPIPE when its input pipe is closed before it's done.

Comment: I have changed wait() position and forbidden  SIGPIPE. The result is same as before.

Comment: Then start to add checks for you return values.